# PHP logging result of function in cron

Tags: php, zend-framework, cron

I have a function in my service and I want to log the result of that function in my cron but for some reason I get a blank line in my console when I run the cron

My function in my service:

```
public function prepare($registeredInNewSiteCheck = false){
        $withdrawals = $this->getVerifiedWithdrawalsToExport();    
        $userService = Zend_Registry::get('container')
            ->get('app.service.user');    
        foreach ($withdrawals as $withdrawal){
            $user = $userService->getUser($withdrawal->getUserID());    
            $idChecked = $user->getIdChecked();    
            return $idChecked;
        }
    }
```

My cron where I try to log the result:

```
$preparedForExport = $withdrawalService->prepare($arguments->registeredInNewSite);
echo 'Log 3 - ' . $preparedForExport . PHP_EOL;
```

The code works great so there's nothing wrong with the code but the log just doesn't work this is my result of my other logs

```
Log 1 - foo
Log 2 - bar
here is supposed to be the Log 3
Log 4 - foo2
```

If anyone has any idea what I am doing wrong pls help me, any help is appreciated!

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: You have a return in a foreach loop. The return will terminate the loop and the function on its first time round the loop

Comment: @RiggsFolly I tried the return outside of the loop and it's still the same problem

Comment: Then thats not the only problem. But we dont see enough code to be able to debug anything else

Comment: @RiggsFolly There is nothing else that applies to my problem

Comment: @RiggsFolly and there is nothing wrong with my cron or service since everything it does everything it's supposed to do and I just want to add some logging feedback

Comment: I have lost count of the number of times I have heard that phrase quoted here ___there is nothing wrong with my cron or service___ Which quite frankly is obviously not true, or you would not be asking a question

Comment: @RiggsFolly I am sorry but it's just true, the only code I added in my service is the `return` and the only code I added in my cron is the echo line and the `$preparedForExport =` and my cron works like I said a number of times :) the problem here is why I get an empty line when I try to echo the result of a function

Comment: Well then you have to look around the line that is not working. If the echo does not happen then that line of code is not getting run. Show a little more code from before that line i.e is it inside some sort of control block (IF/SWITCH) etc